# Access TypeScript function from Javascript callback Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, paypal, callback

I'm successfully rendering a Paypal button in Angular by doing the following:

```
 (window as any).paypal.Buttons({
        createSubscription: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.subscription.create({
                'plan_id': 'XXXXX'
            });
        },
        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
            this.planService.subscribe(1, data.subscriptionID).subscribe(x => alert('SUCCESS'));
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Everything works as expected, but **planService** is undefined when the callback is called, which I understand why, but don't know how to fix. How do I call a Typescript function from the Javascript callback? Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Have you tried passing `onApprove` an arrow function, as in: `onApprove: (data, actions) => {...}`?

Comment: Can't believe that was it. Please submit an answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation lacks the `this` reference, thus `planService` is undefined in the regarding context.
Use an arrow function to bind the current `this` reference to the function:

```
 (window as any).paypal.Buttons({
        createSubscription: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.subscription.create({
                'plan_id': 'XXXXX'
            });
        },
        onApprove: (data, actions) => { // arrow function to bind "this"
            this.planService.subscribe(1, data.subscriptionID).subscribe(x => alert('SUCCESS'));
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

One more thing to note: You may want to check if `this.planService` (assumingly an Observable) runs inside the angular zone. If it does not (because it was triggered by a third party implementation (paypal), you *may* notice that templates do not update accordingly (changes not being picked up by change-detection or change-detection not running as expected).